# Max time to wait for response from CURL request - php

Tags: php, curl

I'm executing a Curl request to an api that regularly times out with a 504 error.
The main problem is that the 504 takes 60 seconds to respond. I'd like to set a max time to wait before moving onto other processes so the 504 doesn't slow everything else down, does anyone know a way to do this with php and Curl, I've tried the following time related options (last 2) within my Curl option settings:

```
// Set curl options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Set curl time options
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 2000); //in miliseconds
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 500); //in miliseconds
```

However timeout and connecttimeout don't seem to do the trick. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: What version of curl is PHP using?

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` and see what curl version it reports. `CURL_VERSION_IPV6` is not a curl version. It just indicates that your version supports IPv6

Comment: Apologies, version is 7.38.0

Comment: apokryfos, any reason for the question re version number?

Comment: Versions prior to 7.16 did not support `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`

Comment: doesn't CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS concern the time required to start the connection? I'm after something that determines when a response is recieved?

Comment: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` is time the connection is allowed to be alive. `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` is time allowed while trying to establish connection.

Comment: ok, I see, that's strange then because I've set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 2000 milliseconds, way below 60 seconds (!) do you know why this may not be working?

Comment: Anyone else know why this isn't working as expected?